# How to consistently texture one object with two materials and two colors?

Tags: texturing, materials

I want to texture one object with two different materials (independently of the mesh) like this for example:
[image: Two materials, one object]

I have one specular texture, one gloss/roughness texture, and one diffuse/albedo texture (the shading will be similar to [this description](https://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/StandardShaderCalibrationChartSpecular.png)).

[image]

If for example the red color should look like plastic and the red color should look like metal, I need to "link" the diffuse texture and the specular and roughness textures together, such that they have the edge between red and blue material exactly at the same point.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use the diffuse texture as a mask for texture painting?

Comment: @HISEROD Maybe I could call it like this, I want to paint the diffuse texture and then when I am painting for example the gloss texture I want to make sure, that I only make the blue part very glossy. I added the node setup, maybe it helps.

Comment: Ok, I get what you're saying, but doing something like this without using a dedicated mask texture is going to be needlessly complex.

Comment: @HISEROD If using a mask texture can I generate in the end the textures "specular", "diffuse","gloss" and "bump"? The thing is, the shading process is given by the game I am targeting.

Comment: If the mask texture is only used in the painting process and not in the node tree, then all the textures will be ready to export as soon as you're done painting.

Answer (score 1):

you can mix shader to add two principled bsdf and use linear and noise like fac: [image]

Comment: I think that is not quite what I am looking for. I have three image textures that I can work with. The nodes that I set up just represent the shading that will happen in the game I am targeting, so I can't really use them. So for example I painted a blue and a red area on the diffuse/albedo texture. Now I want to paint on the blue area but on the specular map, but I don't want to accidentally paint pixels that are red on the albedo image.